# Creating Web-Based Payroll System

Tags: php, html, web-applications, content-management-system

I'm planning to create a Payroll System (web based) with MySQL as a database server. According to what I've researched, it would be easier to create if I will use a CMS. I have difficulties in doing this because I don't know where to start. Can someone tell me what to do or to download in order for me to start this project. Please help.

Comment: This is an extremely complex project. Think carefully about what your requirements are and who you have who can help you. If you want a CMS to use as a base, Wordpress is a good content manager, Drupal is easier to extend. But I'm not sure you do need to start with a CMS.

Comment: A CMS would likely be a horrible base for a web-based payroll system.  You will be building a full-fledged web application, not a store of content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your payroll company needs a building, you'd probably hire a builder.

If you don't know where to start on developing something as critical as a payroll system, I'd suggest that you engage a professional developer...

Or have a search for "Open Source Payroll Software" and see if anything grabs your fancy.